# How to sync form and useState object?

Tags: forms, antd

How do I link a graph using a state to a form, so when the form changes the graph is automatically updated as well, even the form is not submitted yet? The graph is just using showCarrot to generate a chart.js element.

I found `initialValues` as `fields` for forms but do not know how to clue this all together. Anyone can help to save me from insanity?

*Update*: I figured that Ant Design form is based on [field-form](https://github.com/react-component/field-form), still not know how this helps but it is a trail.

---

That's the state I set and propagate to my form and my graph

```
const [showCarrot, setCarrot] = useState<ICarrotArray>([]);
```

That's my form and table to edit the data

```
<Form form={form} initialValues={showCarrot} onFinish={onFinish}>
  <Table
    dataSource={showCarrot}
    rowKey={"id"}
    pagination={false}
    bordered
    footer={(): React.ReactElement => {
      return (
        <Button onClick={addCarrot}>
          <PlusOutlined /> Add Carrot
        </Button>
      );
    }}
  >
  ...
  </Table>
  <br />
  <Row justify="end">
    <Form.Item>
      <Button type="default" onClick={onReset}>
        Restore
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}>
        Save
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </Row>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I just want to understand, correct me if I'm wrong.

You set your initialValues for form which is showCarrot. Is it mean that initialValues set for some Form.Item, because usually object element inside initialValue is used as data for Form.Item by their name.
Like so

```
    <Form
      name="validate_other"
      {...formItemLayout}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      initialValues={{
        ['input-number']: 3, //name of the Form.Item
        ['checkbox-group']: ['A', 'B'],
        rate: 3.5,
      }}
    >
    <Form.Item label="InputNumber">
        <Form.Item name="input-number" noStyle>
          <InputNumber min={1} max={10} />
        </Form.Item>
        <span className="ant-form-text"> machines</span>
      </Form.Item>
```

But by your code it look you want set showCarrot only as table data. If so, I can't find columns in your table, look like currently error because of that. You should add there `dataIndex` param which will listen for your data elements by that name